# Read multiple arguments per line from file and do arithmetic with shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file called `input.txt`:

```
A 1 2
B 3 4
```

Each line of this file means `A=1*2=2` and `B=3*4=12`...
So I want to output such calculation to a file `output.txt`:

```
A=2
B=12
```

And I want to use shell script `calculate.sh` to finish this task:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read name; do
    $var1=$(echo $name | cut -f1)
    $var2=$(echo $name | cut -f2)
    $var3=$(echo $name | cut -f3)
    echo $var1=(expr $var2 * $var3)
done
```

and I type:

```
cat input.txt | ./calculate.sh > output.txt
```

But my approach doesn't work. How to get this task done right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BASH you can do:

```
while read -r a m n; do printf "%s=%d\n" $a $((m*n)); done < input.txt > output.txt

cat output.txt
A=2
B=12
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use awk.

```
$ awk '{print $1"="$2*$3}' file
A=2
B=12
```

Use output redirection operator to store the output to another file.

```
awk '{print $1"="$2*$3}' file > outfile
```

Answer (score 1):

calculate.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read a b c; do
    echo "$a=$((b*c))"
done
```

`bash calculate.sh < input.txt` outputs:

```
A=2
B=12
```

Answer (score 0):

For `bash` doing math requires double parenthesis:

`echo "$((3+4))"`